# django-pagedown seems to be overriding the default Django admin styling -- did I do something wrong with `collectstatic`?

Tags: css, django, django-admin, django-staticfiles, pagedown

I've just installed [django-pagedown](https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-pagedown) according to [this post](http://www.yaconiello.com/blog/part-1-creating-blog-system-using-django-markdown/). I added in all the code and once I did a `./manage.py collectstatic`, I noticed that when I navigated to any DetailPage in the admin (e.g. to add/edit an object), the styling changes.

For example, this is the styling of an object's ListPage:

[image: ListPage styling]

And this is the "new" styling of an object's DetailPage (and where the `AdminPagedownWidget` is located):

[image: DetailPage styling]

The change is pretty subtle -- the font is different / slightly narrower. Of course, this isn't a huge deal, and I'm super stoked to have a live preview of my markdown content... but does anyone know why this is happening? I suspect it has to do with how Django's `collectstatic` works, and `django-pagedown`'s CSS is overriding the default admin's CSS... but it feels to me that the *base* CSS of the admin pages shouldn't be altered, so maybe I've done something wrong when collecting static files. I already took a look at the options that `collectstatic` comes with, and tried it with the `--clean` option, but that didn't seem to solve anything. I looked at the source code and saw that the `pagedown` styles are indeed being loaded after the admin styles, but how would I go about changing that order in the admin interface?

Comment: If you update/reinstall `django-pagedown` it should be fixed now (`pip install django-pagedown==0.0.5`)

Comment: I just reinstalled it and everything looks good. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug. The `AdminPagedownWidget` is also importing the css file for the normal `PagedownWidget` which means there are two css files being imported to your template; the former CSS file ([`demo.css`](https://github.com/timmyomahony/pagedown/blob/master/demo/browser/demo.css#L1)) is imposing a font on the `body` tag.

I'm the `django-pagedown` author so I'll fix it now - well spotted!

**Edit:** If you reinstall/update it should be fixed now `pip install django-pagedown=0.0.5`

Comment: Oh great! I'm really enjoying this app, thanks so much for writing it :)